# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium and need some trail to find root cause of the below error.

Selenium version - 3.5.3 
ChromeDriver version - 2.29.4 
Chrome version - 63

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'BADRI-HP', ip: '---.---.-.---', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\Badri\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir45280_30736}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=63.0.3239.132, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 60b98ca106d00b50963c47e02276c40b
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:370)
    at naukri.ProfileUpdate.login(ProfileUpdate.java:19)
    at testScripts.NewTest.f(NewTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.29.461591*
- Release Notes of [chromedriver=2.29.461591](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome v56-58

- You are using *chrome=63.x*
- Release Notes of [ChromeDriver v2.34](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.34/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome v61-63

- Release Notes of [ChromeDriver v2.35](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome v62-64

- You are using *Selenium Version 3.5.3*.
- Your *JDK version* is *1.8.0_131*.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *chromedriver* version (*v2.29.4*) [which supports *Chrome v56-58*] with the *Chrome Browser* version (*v63.x*) [supported by *ChromeDriver v2.34* minimum]

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels ***JDK Version 8 Update 151***.
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels ***Version 3.8.1***.
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  ***ChromeDriver v2.35*** level.
- Keep *Chrome* to  ***Chrome v64.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- Execute your `Test`.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue after updating chrome driver to 2.38 with chrome version 65.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `ChromeDriver` need to be updated. For `chrome=63.0.3239.132`, you might want to use `ChromeDriver v 2.35`. You can download the same for your system from:

[ChromeDriver v 2.35](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happening intermittently especially when running in parallel mode. Reducing the thread count to 5 from default (10) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using
selenium-java
3.8.1

I need to update and used the latest version it got resolved
Updated to:
selenium-java
4.3.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32193195)