# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Environment:

Selenium webdriver, TestNG, Maven

I am getting this error when I run my script:

> > org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: missing or
> >     invalid 'entry.level'   (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)   (Driver
> >     info: chromedriver=2.29.461591
> >     (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
> >     6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds Build info:
> >     version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time:
> >     '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z' System info: host: 'OWNER', ip: '1x6.1x8.1.1x4', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> >     '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info:
> >     org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverGoogle chrome running on my
> >     machine Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) Java version:
> >     9.0.4

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency> 

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
<artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.8</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
<version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please advise how can I fix the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473618/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-determine-loading)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your

```
chromedriver=2.29.461591
```

to  latest chrome driver.